# Connection is not closed (vb)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, connection

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click

    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Jen\Documents\Jade\vb\database.accdb")

    txtAdmin.Text = "Admin"

    Dim strsql As New OleDbCommand("select * from Account where Username ='" & txtUsername.Text & "' AND [Password] ='" & txtPassword.Text & "' AND AccountType = '" & txtAdmin.Text & "'", conn)
    Dim strsql2 As New OleDbCommand("select * from Account where Username ='" & txtUsername.Text & "' AND [Password] ='" & txtPassword.Text & "' AND AccountType = '" & txtStudent.Text & "'", conn)
    Dim uu As New OleDbParameter("UserName", txtUsername.Text)
    Dim pp As New OleDbParameter("Password", txtPassword.Text)
    strsql.Connection.Open()
    strsql2.Connection.Open()


    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader
    reader = strsql.ExecuteReader

    Dim reader2 As OleDbDataReader
    reader2 = strsql2.ExecuteReader

    If reader.HasRows Then
        strsql.Connection.Close()

        MsgBox(" Welcome Admin!", vbInformation)

        frmIndex.Show()
        desktopFade.Close()

    ElseIf reader2.HasRows Then
        strsql2.Connection.Close()

        MsgBox(" Welcome Student!", vbInformation)

        frmReg.Show()
        desktopFade.Close()

    ElseIf txtUsername.Text = "" And txtPassword.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Don't leave the fields blank", vbCritical)
        txtUsername.Focus()

    Else

        MsgBox("Your Username or Password is invalid", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        Me.txtUsername.Text = ""
        Me.txtPassword.Text = ""
        Me.txtUsername.Focus()
        strsql.Connection.Close()
        strsql2.Connection.Close()

    End If
```

---

The error here is the `strsql2.connection.open()` <---   it says that the connection is not close. still open.

Comment: this could be easily resolved  by using a second connection object for the 2 command object.   Re using connection objects always causes problems.

Comment: a) Many of those db provider objects should be disposed of b) Always use SQL Parameters rather than concat SQL.  Try a user name of `D'Artagnan` to see why c) never, ever store passwords as plaintext, hash them, d) never use default form instances.

Answer (score 0):

I edited your question because you tagged it VBA and this is VB.NET

You have several problems with your code. 
You should add Error trapping with `Try Catch` and also your connection is not always closed

To only fix the actual issue, test if the connection is open before trying to open it

```
        If strsql2.Connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            Console.WriteLine("COnnection already open, closing it")
            strsql2.Connection.Close()
        End If
        strsql2.Connection.Open()
```